# Can't serve Traefik NestJS app in Kubernetes (Bad Gateway)

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, nestjs, traefik

I'm trying to serve an application using NestJS but I'm not being able to do so.

I've already configured Traefik IngressRoutes to serve both Traefik Dashboard and also ArgoCD (and a couple more test apps), but I've been trying to deploy this new application for almost 2 days, without success.

The error is the following:

```
Bad Gateway
```

And this is the log Traefik outputs upon a request:

```
[traefik-c88c9f869-b8cm8] 10.0.1.122 - - [11/Dec/2020:03:13:20 +0000] "GET /graphql HTTP/2.0" 502 11 "-" "-" 764 "develop-business-app-64fa6977f85a45bb4625@kubernetescrd" "http://10.0.3.86:8080" 1ms
```

I don't know if there is any custom configuration I need to do in my app to use HTTP/2.0 or handle Traefik SSL (since the entry point is websecure). I've followed the docs over and over but I always get the same error (I've already tried to remove and installed Traefik again entirely)

Also, if I run `kubectl port-forward` I can use the application as expected.

Here are my configuration files:

This is my Traefik deployment:

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik-proxy
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
    app.kubernetes.io/component: infrastructure
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: traefik
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik-proxy
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
        app.kubernetes.io/component: infrastructure
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      volumes:
        - name: acme-certificates
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v2.3
          args:
            - --accesslog
            - --providers.kubernetescrd
            - --ping
            - --api.dashboard
            - --entrypoints.traefik.address=:8080
            - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
            - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
            - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
            - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver=letsencrypt
            - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=accounts+letsencrypt@getbud.co
            - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/etc/acme/letsencrypt.json
            - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=route53
            - --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.dnsChallenge.delayBeforeCheck=0
          volumeMounts:
            - name: acme-certificates
              mountPath: /etc/acme
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: admin
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 80
              name: web
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 443
              name: websecure
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 1
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
```

This is my application deployment:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: business-app
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: business-app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
    app.kubernetes.io/component: business
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: application-layer
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: business-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: business-app
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
        app.kubernetes.io/component: business
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: application-layer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: business-app
          image: 904333181156.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/business:$ECR_TAG <- this is updated with the latest tag using envsubst
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: web
              protocol: TCP
```

This is my application service:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: business-app
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: business-app
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

And this is my IngressRoute:

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: business-app
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: business-app
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.0
    app.kubernetes.io/component: business
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: application-layer
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`api.develop.getbud.co`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: business-app
          port: 80
  tls:
    certResolver: letsencrypt
    options: {}
```

Can someone give me a hint on what am I doing wrong?

Just an update, I've changed the loglevel of traefik to debug, and here is what it logs upon request:

```
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:31Z" level=debug msg="Error while Peeking first byte: read tcp 10.0.3.86:80->10.0.1.122:44996: read: connection reset by peer"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:31Z" level=debug msg="Error while Peeking first byte: read tcp 10.0.3.86:8080->10.0.3.100:6380: read: connection reset by peer"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: begin ServeHttp on request" Request="{\"Method\":\"GET\",\"URL\":{\"Scheme\":\"\",\"Opaque\":\"\",\"User\":null,\"Host\":\"\",\"Path\":\"/graphql\",\"RawPath\":\"\",\"ForceQuery\":false,\"RawQuery\":\"\",\"Fragment\":\"\",\"RawFragment\":\"\"},\"Proto\":\"HTTP/2.0\",\"ProtoMajor\":2,\"ProtoMinor\":0,\"Header\":{\"Accept\":[\"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip, deflate, br\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-US,pt-BR;q=0.5\"],\"Cache-Control\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Pragma\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Te\":[\"trailers\"],\"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests\":[\"1\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\"],\"X-Forwarded-Host\":[\"api.develop.getbud.co\"],\"X-Forwarded-Port\":[\"443\"],\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":[\"https\"],\"X-Forwarded-Server\":[\"traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c\"],\"X-Real-Ip\":[\"10.0.1.122\"]},\"ContentLength\":0,\"TransferEncoding\":null,\"Host\":\"api.develop.getbud.co\",\"Form\":null,\"PostForm\":null,\"MultipartForm\":null,\"Trailer\":null,\"RemoteAddr\":\"10.0.1.122:27473\",\"RequestURI\":\"/graphql\",\"TLS\":null}"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: Forwarding this request to URL" Request="{\"Method\":\"GET\",\"URL\":{\"Scheme\":\"\",\"Opaque\":\"\",\"User\":null,\"Host\":\"\",\"Path\":\"/graphql\",\"RawPath\":\"\",\"ForceQuery\":false,\"RawQuery\":\"\",\"Fragment\":\"\",\"RawFragment\":\"\"},\"Proto\":\"HTTP/2.0\",\"ProtoMajor\":2,\"ProtoMinor\":0,\"Header\":{\"Accept\":[\"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip, deflate, br\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-US,pt-BR;q=0.5\"],\"Cache-Control\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Pragma\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Te\":[\"trailers\"],\"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests\":[\"1\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\"],\"X-Forwarded-Host\":[\"api.develop.getbud.co\"],\"X-Forwarded-Port\":[\"443\"],\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":[\"https\"],\"X-Forwarded-Server\":[\"traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c\"],\"X-Real-Ip\":[\"10.0.1.122\"]},\"ContentLength\":0,\"TransferEncoding\":null,\"Host\":\"api.develop.getbud.co\",\"Form\":null,\"PostForm\":null,\"MultipartForm\":null,\"Trailer\":null,\"RemoteAddr\":\"10.0.1.122:27473\",\"RequestURI\":\"/graphql\",\"TLS\":null}" ForwardURL="http://10.0.1.158:8080"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="'502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp 10.0.1.158:8080: connect: connection refused"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: completed ServeHttp on request" Request="{\"Method\":\"GET\",\"URL\":{\"Scheme\":\"\",\"Opaque\":\"\",\"User\":null,\"Host\":\"\",\"Path\":\"/graphql\",\"RawPath\":\"\",\"ForceQuery\":false,\"RawQuery\":\"\",\"Fragment\":\"\",\"RawFragment\":\"\"},\"Proto\":\"HTTP/2.0\",\"ProtoMajor\":2,\"ProtoMinor\":0,\"Header\":{\"Accept\":[\"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip, deflate, br\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-US,pt-BR;q=0.5\"],\"Cache-Control\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Pragma\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Te\":[\"trailers\"],\"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests\":[\"1\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\"],\"X-Forwarded-Host\":[\"api.develop.getbud.co\"],\"X-Forwarded-Port\":[\"443\"],\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":[\"https\"],\"X-Forwarded-Server\":[\"traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c\"],\"X-Real-Ip\":[\"10.0.1.122\"]},\"ContentLength\":0,\"TransferEncoding\":null,\"Host\":\"api.develop.getbud.co\",\"Form\":null,\"PostForm\":null,\"MultipartForm\":null,\"Trailer\":null,\"RemoteAddr\":\"10.0.1.122:27473\",\"RequestURI\":\"/graphql\",\"TLS\":null}"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] 10.0.1.122 - - [11/Dec/2020:04:54:32 +0000] "GET /graphql HTTP/2.0" 502 11 "-" "-" 754 "develop-business-app-64fa6977f85a45bb4625@kubernetescrd" "http://10.0.1.158:8080" 2ms
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="Error while Peeking first byte: read tcp 10.0.3.86:443->10.0.3.75:35314: read: connection reset by peer"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: begin ServeHttp on request" Request="{\"Method\":\"GET\",\"URL\":{\"Scheme\":\"\",\"Opaque\":\"\",\"User\":null,\"Host\":\"\",\"Path\":\"/favicon.ico\",\"RawPath\":\"\",\"ForceQuery\":false,\"RawQuery\":\"\",\"Fragment\":\"\",\"RawFragment\":\"\"},\"Proto\":\"HTTP/2.0\",\"ProtoMajor\":2,\"ProtoMinor\":0,\"Header\":{\"Accept\":[\"image/webp,*/*\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip, deflate, br\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-US,pt-BR;q=0.5\"],\"Cache-Control\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Pragma\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Referer\":[\"https://api.develop.getbud.co/graphql\"],\"Te\":[\"trailers\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\"],\"X-Forwarded-Host\":[\"api.develop.getbud.co\"],\"X-Forwarded-Port\":[\"443\"],\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":[\"https\"],\"X-Forwarded-Server\":[\"traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c\"],\"X-Real-Ip\":[\"10.0.1.122\"]},\"ContentLength\":0,\"TransferEncoding\":null,\"Host\":\"api.develop.getbud.co\",\"Form\":null,\"PostForm\":null,\"MultipartForm\":null,\"Trailer\":null,\"RemoteAddr\":\"10.0.1.122:27473\",\"RequestURI\":\"/favicon.ico\",\"TLS\":null}"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: Forwarding this request to URL" ForwardURL="http://10.0.1.158:8080" Request="{\"Method\":\"GET\",\"URL\":{\"Scheme\":\"\",\"Opaque\":\"\",\"User\":null,\"Host\":\"\",\"Path\":\"/favicon.ico\",\"RawPath\":\"\",\"ForceQuery\":false,\"RawQuery\":\"\",\"Fragment\":\"\",\"RawFragment\":\"\"},\"Proto\":\"HTTP/2.0\",\"ProtoMajor\":2,\"ProtoMinor\":0,\"Header\":{\"Accept\":[\"image/webp,*/*\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip, deflate, br\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-US,pt-BR;q=0.5\"],\"Cache-Control\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Pragma\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Referer\":[\"https://api.develop.getbud.co/graphql\"],\"Te\":[\"trailers\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\"],\"X-Forwarded-Host\":[\"api.develop.getbud.co\"],\"X-Forwarded-Port\":[\"443\"],\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":[\"https\"],\"X-Forwarded-Server\":[\"traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c\"],\"X-Real-Ip\":[\"10.0.1.122\"]},\"ContentLength\":0,\"TransferEncoding\":null,\"Host\":\"api.develop.getbud.co\",\"Form\":null,\"PostForm\":null,\"MultipartForm\":null,\"Trailer\":null,\"RemoteAddr\":\"10.0.1.122:27473\",\"RequestURI\":\"/favicon.ico\",\"TLS\":null}"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="'502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp 10.0.1.158:8080: connect: connection refused"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] time="2020-12-11T04:54:32Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: completed ServeHttp on request" Request="{\"Method\":\"GET\",\"URL\":{\"Scheme\":\"\",\"Opaque\":\"\",\"User\":null,\"Host\":\"\",\"Path\":\"/favicon.ico\",\"RawPath\":\"\",\"ForceQuery\":false,\"RawQuery\":\"\",\"Fragment\":\"\",\"RawFragment\":\"\"},\"Proto\":\"HTTP/2.0\",\"ProtoMajor\":2,\"ProtoMinor\":0,\"Header\":{\"Accept\":[\"image/webp,*/*\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip, deflate, br\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-US,pt-BR;q=0.5\"],\"Cache-Control\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Pragma\":[\"no-cache\"],\"Referer\":[\"https://api.develop.getbud.co/graphql\"],\"Te\":[\"trailers\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\"],\"X-Forwarded-Host\":[\"api.develop.getbud.co\"],\"X-Forwarded-Port\":[\"443\"],\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":[\"https\"],\"X-Forwarded-Server\":[\"traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c\"],\"X-Real-Ip\":[\"10.0.1.122\"]},\"ContentLength\":0,\"TransferEncoding\":null,\"Host\":\"api.develop.getbud.co\",\"Form\":null,\"PostForm\":null,\"MultipartForm\":null,\"Trailer\":null,\"RemoteAddr\":\"10.0.1.122:27473\",\"RequestURI\":\"/favicon.ico\",\"TLS\":null}"
[traefik-55888dfd67-r8b2c] 10.0.1.122 - - [11/Dec/2020:04:54:32 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 502 11 "-" "-" 755 "develop-business-app-64fa6977f85a45bb4625@kubernetescrd" "http://10.0.1.158:8080" 1ms
```

So, it seems Traefik is receiving a connection refused from the pod. I've opened a shell inside Traefik's container and tried to run wget directly in the Pod IP and indeed I received the same error (connection refused).

Any other working pod whenever I ran wget it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who (like me) are struggling with this issue, here is the problems:

Fastify by default listens only at `127.0.0.1`, so, it automatically refuses any other host connection. To solve that you can simply add `0.0.0.0` as the second argument of your `app.listen` call, like the following:

previous:

```
  await app.listen(appConfig.port)
```

fixed:

```
  await app.listen(appConfig.port, '0.0.0.0')
```

Thanks in any case :)